# Python object does not sort with like objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe column of dtype *objects* that does not sort properly. I need it to stay object due to the possibility of strings, `Load` in the example.

The object in the *Index 6 row* appears the exact same but does not sort with the rest. If I convert the column to *string* type it adds a `.0` to the end of each object in *column1*, except the object in the *Index 6 row*. I cannot convert to *int* because I need *strings* to remain. How can I fix the sorting? Thank you.

Edit:

**Figured out issue -** 10 is *string* object.

Ex:

```
Index     column1
0         10
1         10
2         11
3         11
4         11
5         11
6         10
7         Load
```

Comment: So you are trying to sort a mix of strings and ints?  Is 'Load' smaller or larger than 11?

Comment: Load is larger than 11. The actual data frame is several hundred rows and sorts fine. There is an issue with the 10 in row 6 as for some reason it is not the same value, maybe not actually an int.

Comment: Probably  just a stray space. Try trimming..

Comment: Trimming replaces all values except the 10 and Load with NaN.

Comment: Then 10 is a string type. Happy days

Comment: Can I convert just that? Converting the column to int will cause issue with Load string. The 10 may not always be in the same place, either.  Thank you for the insight. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all elements of the dataframe `df` that you wish to sort on to numeric type, then obtain the indices of the sort, and use those to reorder the original series

```
import pandas as pd 
inds = (pd.to_numeric(df['column1']))).argsort() # use these indices to sort original df
```

This shouldn't modify the dtype of the original dataframe.

Comment: I may be missing something but the string Load does not parse correctly with that. I used `error="coerce"` to correct. Passing `ind` to `pd.reindex()` does not use it appropriately though.

Comment: I used `.fillna(999)` prior to `.argsort()` to correct and put strings at end